# Find most accurate classifier for my data automatically

Tags: windows, machine-learning, classification, weka

I am using Weka, and I'm trying to find the most accurate classifier for my dataset.

The interface for selecting a classifier looks like the following:

[image]

It works fine, but it only lets me select one classifier at a time, which is not very practical.

Can I somehow make it run all the available classifiers on my data, so I can easily find the most accurate one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use weka Experimenter.  See below image. I have chosen one data set and two different classification algorithm.
See following tutorial for more information , 
[WEKA Experimenter Tutorial](http://www.unimaas.nl/datamining/experimenter.pdf).

[image: Weka Experimenter Sample Image]